# Reporting on Case owner and Case Team Member

Tags: reporting, case, service, case-teams, cloud

We use Case teams and want to be able to report if the support engineer is either the owner or on the case team.  This way we know the support engineers total workload.  I created a report type linking Case Team and Case and it all looks swell when I create the report except the results don't include cases where there is no case team.  it picks up where the support engineer is the owner and there is a case team and also where the support engineer is on a case team but not the owner but never where the support engineer is the owner and there is no case team.  I've tried "With name = "" in the criteria but still nothing.  In fact, as long as"name" is a column in the report, cases with no case team don't show up.  Is this doable?  Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your report type structure - is it cases w case teams or case teams w cases?  If the former, have you tried a w or w out report type, ie cases w or w out case teams.  On mobile now so hard to poke on it.  If all else fails, a trigger to automatically add case owner to case team could get you there.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information by running queries.

1. Go to workbench.developerforce.com
2. Login using your Salesforce credentials
3. Select the SOQL Query option
4. For Object, choose the CaseShare object.
5. Enter the following query in the "Enter or Modify a SOQL query" field: SELECT CaseAccessLevel,CaseId,Id,IsDeleted,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,RowCause,UserOrGroupId FROM CaseShare WHERE IsDeleted = FALSE
   6.Choose the "Bulk CSV" option under the "View As" field.
   7.Click on the query button.
   8.Download results by clicking on blue arrow.
   9.Go back to the SOQL screen and choose User as the object. 
   10.Enter the following query in the "Enter or Modify an SOQL query" field: SELECT Id,IsActive,Name FROM User WHERE IsActive = True
6. Select Bulk CSV in the View As: field.
   12.Click on the query button.
7. Click on the download button with the blue arrow.
8. Now that you have exported both queries out to Excel use VLookup to match the UserOrGroupId column on the CaseShare table with the ID column on the User table and return the Name column value on the User table to the CaseShare table.

This will show every Case the user has access to whether it is because of ownership, Teams, Manual connection, Rule, or being an implicit child. The RowCause field on the CaseShare object notes the reason why the user has access. The values for the RowCause field are Implicit Child, Manual,Owner, Rule, Team. If you have questions on VLookup, leave a comment and I can provide instructions for that. Hopefully this is helpful to you.